# Does exist any miniPC with WinCE

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I would like to get a miniPC with WinCE 7 OS, does any analogs exist like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-arrival-YC-U1-Android-Google-TV-Player-Dual-Core-4GB-Memory-Mini-PC-Black-/221075632051?pt=US_Internet_Media_Streamers&hash=item3379226fb3#ht_5536wt_1141) or [this](http://www.ovalelephant.com/p-2077-new-dual-core-rockchip-3066-android-mini-pc-android-1gb-ddr3-ram) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The eBox 3300MX](http://www.wdlsystems.com/modperl/view_services.cgi?r=detail&prod_num=1EB33AJ&aisle_id=1073) ships with CE 6.0R3 but there's [a 7.0 BSP available](http://www.embeddedpc.net/FilesDownload/tabid/66/ArticleId/19/eBox-3300MX.aspx), so getting 7.0 on to it is pretty simple.